# Error in terminal when trying to run composer

Tags: json, terminal, composer-php, silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe site with the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "*",
        "silverstripe/userforms": "*",
        "silverstripe/widgets": "*",
        "silverstripe/spamprotection": "*",
        "silverstripe/blog": "dev-master",
        "silverstripe/comments": "dev-master",
        "silverstripe/lumberjack": "~1.1",
        "undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield": "dev-master",
        "axllent/silverstripe-version-truncator": "dev-master",
        "unclecheese/betterbuttons": "dev-master",
        "jonom/focuspoint": "dev-master",
        "silverbusters/silverstripe-simplelistfield": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600  
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

When I try to execute this script within Apple terminal, using `php composer.phar install -dev`, I receive the following error message:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for silverstripe/framework 3.2.1 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.2.1].
> - jonom/focuspoint dev-master requires silverstripe/framework ^3.3 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.3.0.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: silverstripe/framework[3.3.0.x-dev, 3.2.1].
> - Can only install one of: silverstripe/framework[3.3.x-dev, 3.2.1].
> - Can only install one of: silverstripe/framework[3.x-dev, 3.2.1].
> - Can only install one of: silverstripe/framework[3.4.x-dev, 3.2.1].
> - Installation request for jonom/focuspoint dev-master -> satisfiable by jonom/focuspoint[dev-master].

This worked fine in early January for me. How should I modify my JSON file so this works correctly?

Answer (score 3):

FocusPoint in "dev-master" version is only compatible with Silverstripe version 3.3. You have three possibilities:

- install the version of 3.3 (not stable) of Silverstripe in order to make FocusPoint work.
- don't install `jonom/focuspoint`
- install an older version of `jonom/focuspoint` (ex: 1.1.1)

You just have to edit your `composer.json` file and change the versions numbers.

Comment: Ok, from what I can see in the JSON file I'm not telling it to install focuspoint. why would it be doing this? not sure which version numebrs i need to change?

Comment: If you don't want focuspoint, remove this line: `"jonom/focuspoint": "dev-master"`

Comment: thanks, I'm a bit of a newbie programmer but youve helped big time.